# startActivityForResult() from a Fragment and finishing child Activity, doesn't call onActivityResult() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

`FirstActivity.Java` has a `FragmentA.Java` which calls `startActivityForResult()`.
`SecondActivity.Java` call `finish()` but `onActivityResult` never get called which is 
written in `FragmentA.Java`.

`FragmentA.Java` code:

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // some code
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("helloString", helloString);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    getActivity();
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       //some code
    }
  }
```

`SecondActivity.Java` code:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //some code
       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
       returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);                          

       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
       finish();
  }
```

I have tried debugging the code, but `onAcitvityResult()` never get called.

Comment: Try to put it (onActivityResult method) in the FirstActivity class

Comment: possible duplicate of [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You must write `onActivityResult()` in your `FirstActivity.Java` as follows

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So this will call your fragment's `onActivityResult()`

**Edit:** the solution is to replace `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);` with `startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

Comment: Thanks @Kevin , i tried what you said but it's not working.
But i debugged the code, i see `onActivityresult()` of `FirstAcivity.Java` gets called and `onActivityresult()` of `FragmentA.Java` never get called. Please help.

Comment: Please replace getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1); with startActivityForResult(i, 1);

Comment: Could it be that the answer in the accepted solution is actually not what is wrong here, and the *real* solution is to just use `startActivityForResult` instead of `getActivity().start...`? Because as far as I can see, you are overriding the definition of `onActivityResult` with its own definition, in the Activity (i.e. this behaves exactly the same as if the override in the answer did not exist).

Comment: @asQuirreL Yes. this is probably the reason.

Comment: @amnn Actually, BOTH of those are issues.  I had already removed my `getActivity()` but still wasn't getting the result in the fragment until I added the `super` call to my Activity.

Comment: As long as the only thing you are doing in the you are doing is calling the super method, you don't even need to override it. Your solution works though.

Comment: in my case i had to use `((Activity) getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: I do the same as you explain, override onActivityResult() in activity also in fragment with super in both and make startActivityForResult (intent ,i), but did not work, I need help please

Comment: To note on this, always call the super in activity's onActivityResult and use fragment's startActivityForResult. May the force be with you.

Comment: This did not work for me as well

Answer (score 34):

Kevin's answer works but It makes it hard to play with the data using that solution.

Best solution is don't start `startActivityForResult()` on activity level.

in your case don't call `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

Instead, just use `startActivityForResult()` and it will work perfectly fine! :)

Answer (score 31):

You must write onActivityResult() in your FirstActivity.Java as follows

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This will trigger onActivityResult method of fragments on FirstActivity.java

Comment: thanks mate ! but it requiere a Level 26 API .. so in my case I used getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag method but with your idea

Answer (score 15):

The fragment already has `startActivityForResult`, which would call `onActivityResult` in the fragment if you use it, instead of `getActivity()`...

Answer (score 10):

The most important thing, that all are missing here is...
The launchMode of FirstActivity must be singleTop. If it is singleInstance, the onActivityResult in FragmentA will be called just after calling the startActivityForResult method. So, It will not wait for calling of the finish() method in SecondActivity.

So go through the following steps, It will definitely work as it worked for me too after a long research.

In AndroidManifest.xml file, make launchMode of FirstActivity.Java as singleTop.

```
<activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

In FirstActivity.java, override onActivityResult method. As this will call the onActivityResult of FragmentA.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In FragmentA.Java, override onActivityResult method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("FragmentA.java","onActivityResult called");
}
```

Call `startActivityForResult(intent, HOMEWORK_POST_ACTIVITY);` from FragmentA.Java

Call `finish();` method in SecondActivity.java

Hope this will work.

Comment: This is the best answer. The detail of defining the "launchMode" in the Manifest is vital.

Comment: This did not work for me, FirstActivity onActivityResult did not even execute

Answer (score 6):

We could call `startActivityForResult()` directly from Fragment
So You should call `this.startActivityForResult(i, 1);` instead of `getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("helloString", helloString);
this.startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Activity will send the Activity Result to your Fragment.

Answer (score 2):

May it's late for the answer. But will be helpful for anyone.

In My case want to call activity from Fragment and setResult back from the fragment.

I have used getContext of Fragment Like.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getContext(), NextActivity.class), 111);
```

And Set Result from Fragment

```
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    getActivity().finish();
```

Now Getting Result to Fragment with

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 111) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this:

```html
//don't call getActivity()
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);

//just call 
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
//directly from fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult()  of MAinActivity will call  ,  onActivityResult()  of Fragement wont call because   fragment is placed in Activity so obviously it come back to MainActivity

Answer (score -2):

Don't call `finish()` in `onCreate()` method then it works fine.

Comment: Please explain this a bit further, curious to know what you were doing