# Why am I getting class cast exception? Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an android app that is supposed to load the gallery and grab an image and display it in an image view. I had it working but changed from Activities to Fragments to use the ViewPager and since then it has been crashing. I believe it is because I'm using a method intended for Activities on Fragments.

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.v("ButtonPress: ", "Pressed");

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            Log.v("ButtonPress: ", "intent=" + i);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK    && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}

}
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610): Process: com.example.hashtagged, PID: 32610
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hashtagged/com.example.hashtagged.Fragment_1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.hashtagged.Fragment_1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2131)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5142)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.hashtagged.Fragment_1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
05-05 22:17:59.214: E/AndroidRuntime(32610):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inflate the View first on OnCreateView, like this:

```
private Button mButtonLoadImage;

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
  mButtonLoadImage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
  return view;
}
```

And set onClickListener inside onViewCreated:

```
@Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  mButtonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(onClickLoad);
}

//Good practice
private View.OnClickListener onClickLoad = new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    //TODO action here
  }
};
```

Comment: Just tried that and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error but my code does look nicer. Thanks!

Comment: Insert a Try / Catch inside onActivityResult() method. in Catch do this:

    catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Why you doing it inside onActivityResult()? You can do it inside onViewCreated very well...

Comment: I was attemping to follow this tutorial but it won't work for me with Fragments. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Comment: Comment all the code inside the if statement and put a System.out.println ("Your message here");
Go uncomment each line and try to find the error.

Comment: I realized it would be a lot easier to just change a lot of my code to use Activities and take on learning Fragments on another day. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: If you can avoid fragments, avoid them as much as possible, is less code in your application. : p

Answer (score 0):

You are using onActivityResult() method of the activity class in your Fragment class. That is why you are getting this error. onActivityResult should be defined in your activity class of the your fragment class not on the fragment itself. See this link for how to do it.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c)

Comment: This is my first time using Fragments. I have the following classes:
Main Activity: Just Sets up ViewPager
myPageAdapter: Page Adapter class
Fragment_1: The code that I posted above
Fragment_2: Nothing
Fragment_3: Nothing

So basically I need to create an activity for each fragment or can I just move the onActivityResult to my MainActivity?