# How do I programmatically navigate from an activity to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

How do I navigate back from an activity to a fragment, after I pressed a button in activity?

This is what I'm doing:

1. I call my activity from the fragment to pass data
2. After I pass data, I want the control to automatically move back to fragment

Comment: You want to implement backPress click ?

Comment: i call an activity from fragment. in activity i make a request, after the request delivered, activity automatically back to fragment it. how to make it?

Comment: Did you try just to call finish(); after the request has been delivered?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on your activity after you finish work there call:

```
onBackPressed();
```

But the best way to achieve this is by calling startActivityForResult from your fragment, it calls your Activity and after you finish work there you return to your fragment.

Here is an example how to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c)