# how to send data from activity to fragment when user clicks on back button in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that opens up a new activity. how can I pass data back to the fragment from that activity when user clicks on back button?
I've tried creating a new `Intent` and put data in there then call `setResult()`, but neither the `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` got anything in `onActivityResult`. the only way I can think of now is through static method, but still want to see if there's a proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: you can `startActivityForResult()` from activity

Comment: but I already hit back button meaning i wanted to close out that activity. is it necessary to call `startActivityForResult()` ?

Comment: use `startActivityForResult()` and then `setResult` inside activity `onBackPressed()`..

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920306/sending-data-back-to-the-main-activity-in-android

Comment: check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c

Comment: weird...how come my `onActivityResult` is called right away when I call `startActivityForResult() ` and pressing the back button doesn't call  `onActivityResult` again

Comment: @Muhammad Babar I was thinking about that too but thought there might be some builtin I can utilize.

Comment: @user1865027 The easiest solution  is your activity already have the fragment instance use that to pass any data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling static function and assigning is not a proper solution. you can use interface call back or you can use startActivityForResult() method.

interface callback basic idea ;

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{

private MyListener mFragmentCallbackListener; 

  public YourActivity(MyListener listener){
   mFragmentCallbackListener = listener;
  } 

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed(){

 if(mFragmentCallbackListener != null){
   mFragmentCallbackListener.updateFragment(String data);
  }
 }

 public interface MyListener{
  void updateFragment(String data)
 }  
}
```

Comment: still cant get startActivityForResult() to work, so i end up using interface

Answer (score 0):

> I have a fragment that opens up a new activity

Start your Activity using `startActivityForResult()` instead of  `startActivity()`

> I've tried creating a new Intent and put data in there then call setResult(), but neither the Fragment or FragmentActivity got anything in onActivityResult.

If you are using `startActivityForResult()` then the `onActivityResult()` will be called after you finished that Acivity.