# onActivityResult() in Fragments Anjlab

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I completely tried solutions given on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131171/calling-startintentsenderforresult-from-fragment-android-billing-v3)

I have tried `startActivityForResult` and `startIntentSenderForResult` But it's not work for me.Honestly, I'm not sure to I get it. Simply I use this code my activity and works fine but it's not working on the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: add onActivity result in activty of your fragment and pass it to your fragment .it will work

Comment: In which activty ? I use Tablayout and this is tab2 (fragment2)

Comment: In activity where you are initializing your tabs add your activity and tab fragment code.

Comment: You have not shown the calling code, but ensure Fragment.startActivityForResult() is called not Activity.startActivityForResult().

Comment: If you call `startActivityForResult` in fragment, you get the result in fragment. If you call it in activity (or from fragment but with `getActivity().startActivityFromResult`) you get the result in the activity.

Comment: Do I use something code as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622311/how-can-i-call-onactivityresult-inside-fragment-and-how-it-work/44622456#44622456 on activty.Do I have to change anything on activty.Is it possiable to finish in fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6147884/4395804)  and read this answer [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061844/4395804), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/4395804)

I think when you add startActivityForResult, that time use context of getActivity().

Add `getActivity().startActivityForResult();`