# Using Stripe payment methods with custom interface in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, android-dialogfragment

I am working on integrating Stripe in our app. I want to add and accept cards through either a `DialogFragment` or an `Activity` with a custom layout instead of the [Stripe-provided activities](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic). I know I can use the provided views like `CardInputWidget` individually to build a UI, and I am successful in creating a `DialogFragment` that can take input for card information and perform validation accordingly.

But the problem is in setting up a flow to get results from the `DialogFragment`. Stripe [uses onActivityResult](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic#manage) to know whether the payment session was successful or not in adding a card. Is there a workaround to do this in my `DialogFragment`? If not, then how can I create an `Activity` with a custom layout to handle all this?

Comment: Abdul, you don't really need onActivityResult in this case; all you need is to 
1. Create a payment method with `PaymentMethodCreateParams.Card` with the data you've collected in your custom form 2. confirm the paymentIntent call `confirmPayment` with client secret and the payment method created at 1. 
This could all be called in an event listener than the activityResult callback

Comment: how we could provide custome UI for strip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onActivityResult()` in Fragments too (it also applies to `DialogFragment`).

```
class CardFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        
        if (requestCode == 12345) doSomething()
    }
}
```

Further info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622311/how-can-i-call-onactivityresult-inside-fragment-and-how-it-work).