# Android: How to programmatically click on a button previously located in an activity in the activity stack, from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult

When I am in a fragmentB, how to simulate a click on a button located in an activity in the stack.

LoginActivityA => fragmentB.

I want to simulate something like this:

> LoginActivityA.btnClick() from the fragmentB

I tried to use this tickets with no success:  [Ticket1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578803/3581620), [Ticket2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622657/3581620), [Ticket3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/3581620)
Here is my code:
FragmentB:

```
//BEGIN TEST
String message="hello ";
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);
getActivity().setResult(2,intent);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,2);
getActivity().finish();//finishing activity
//END TEST
```

LoginActivityA:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if(requestCode==2)
        {
            //do the things u wanted
        }
    }
```

I precise that I try not to get multiple LoginActivity and Fragment launched. I would like to get only one stack with LoginActivity => Fragment

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I tried this from [this tichet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659795/3581620) with no success:

```
((LoginActivity)getActivity()).login();
```

I launched the activity function from the presented fragment with an error

> "No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is
>   0."

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface with an onClick method that is implemented by your activity and then in fragment B call the method onClick whenever you want and pass the activity to it.

Although I presume what you are doing is wrong and you should change your mind around it.

Comment: hi! I can do that, but how to call a function in the A activity from the stack?

Comment: @ΩlostA isn't LoginActivityA,  FragmentB's host?

Comment: yes it is. The first view launched is the loginActivityA, and then the FragmentB

Comment: Ok. So you can get activityA in Fragment be :
fragmentB.getActivity()

Comment: I get " No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0." by doing activityA activity = (activityA) fragmentB.this.getActivity();

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice, but if you want you can call your activity UI elements by

`((Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_id)).performClick();`

Always remember, Android is a well architect platform, if you are trying to do something which is difficult, probably you should not do it. Rethink about your your design patterns.