# How to call onActivityResult from non activity class

Tags: android

I'd like to get data when startActivityForResult from non Activity, please for me some sugession.

For example:

Fragment A--> non Activity class, startActivityForResult here, and how to get data on FragmentA

FragmentA

```
DownloadFile files = DownLoadFile.loadFiles(getActivity)

class DownloadFile

{

public static void loadFiles()

{
Intent = new Intent(...)

startActivityForResult 

}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c

Comment: Just use interfaces. Pass to your non-activity class as listeners.

Answer (score 0):

u can do a callback on FragmentA and in DownloadFile to invoke it!

Comment: I tried, but can not do that, because we on FragmentA can not get data when we turn on setResult

Comment: u use the startActivityForResult or getActivity().startActivityForResult?

Comment: yes, but how to setResult to FragmentA which can get data. I need get data on FragmentA when startActivityForResult on non activity class.

Answer (score 0):

***onActivityResult() is a method in the class Activity. Therefore if you're not extending Activity, you can't override it***

You need an Activity on order to receive the result of the action. If it is just for reuse and organisation then  just call your other class from your Activity?

```
public class DownloadFile {
    public static void loadFiles(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        ...
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   DownloadFile.loadFiles(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it's not possible, as on non activity class can not call setResult or any thing about ActivityResult