# startActivityForResult not working in fragment and not start an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to `startActivityForResult` in my fragment and i do this way:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
.....
 new GetNidBase(getContext(), code, Integer.parseInt(_newBlock.split("-")[3]),
     WKT1, user, cookie, permissions, _newBlock, (nidBase) -> {
     if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nidBase)) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), FormSaveDocument.class);
         intent.putExtra(BaseFragment.ARG_COOKIE, HttpUtil.serializeCookie(cookie));
         intent.putExtra(BaseFragment.ARG_USER, common.Utils.compactUserInstance(user));
         intent.putExtra(BaseFragment.ARG_PERMISSIONS, GsonUtil.createGson().toJson(permissions));
         startActivityForResult(intent, INTENTRESULT);
         }
```

I want to handle my result in fragment's onActivityForResult() But i wondered that, `FormSaveDocument` is not started? `FormSaveDocument` is a activity class!!`startActivityForResult(intent, INTENTRESULT)` not work.

I also trying this:

```
MyFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, INTENTRESULT);
```

This is `onActivityResult` in my fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == INTENTRESULT && resultCode == 20) {
        saveDraw();
    }
}
```

> Update

This is myActivity and FormSaveDocument manifest info:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <activity
        android:name=".forms.FormSaveDocument"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `resultCode == 20`

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: are you using context from parent activity? I'm assuming that `requireContext()` is getting the context from parent activity. Is there any error logs? If there are any logs, please add some logs.

Comment: I am calling startActivityForResult() from the fragment then i should call startActivityForResult() and i do it ... @akshay_shahane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [startActivityForResult() from a Fragment and finishing child Activity, doesn't call onActivityResult() in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c)

Comment: "But i wondered that, `FormSaveDocument` is not started?" – If you mean that `FormSaveDocument` is not showing at all, are you sure that that code is executing?

Comment: are you using context from parent activity? If course, `requireContext()` comes from parent @AmolG

Comment: make sure your Host Activity launch mode must not set to singleInstance or singleTask

Comment: In activity i do :  `myFragment.setArguments(args);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(MyFragment.getClass().getName())
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, myFragment)
                    .commit();`  @akshay_shahane

Comment: is there any error logs? does the activity is able to start from other ways without any error?

Comment: I do not have any error and logcat is not showing any error and i did not get any error.Just do not started my activity@AmolG

Comment: Share manifest.

Comment: Do you have an  `<activity>` element for `FormSaveDocument`?

Comment: @MikeM. ops i forgot to add .. I updated my question

Comment: It's really starting to sound like that `startActivityForResult()` line isn't being reached. You might try setting a breakpoint there, or put a log print, or something, just to make sure.

Comment: is it because of  !TextUtils.isEmpty(nidBase) always false?

Comment: I am sure the cursor reach to `startActivityForResult()` and pass from it but `FormSaveDocument` not started and i got any error @MikeM

Comment: I am taking a picture from break point to see cursor reach @MikeM.

Comment: This is  my debug photo : http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=ceb599c19f7188bfa43f0b8ee41e00d2   @MikeM.

Comment: Well, if `FormSaveDocument` is failing when starting up, there really should be something in [your logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running). If you're not seeing anything, you might post `FormSaveDocument` in your question, to see if we notice anything that could be causing an issue.

Comment: I am trying to check deeper ..Thanks so much @MikeM

Answer (score 0):

In Your Activity Where you get your result back you have to use same object of fragment which you used to add Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Please use
`startActivityForResult(intent, INTENTRESULT);` insted of call `MyFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, INTENTRESULT);`   from your fragment, and

Then after handle `onActivityResult()` in your fragment

This will give you call back in your fragment

**Another Solution is:**
Handle `onActivityResult` in your activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            getCurrentFrg().onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);    
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: dude, I said above that  I also tried  `MyFragment.this.startActivityForResult` but first i use `startActivityForResult` and i did not get answer

Comment: Okay, Then the final solution is called as you calling and handle onActivityResult in your activity and call fragment onActivityResult  from the activity callBack

Comment: dude my problem is `startActivityForResult`, not ` onActivityResult` @DhavalSolanki