# how can I implement a return from the activity to the fragment that called it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Please tell me how can I implement a return from the activity to the fragment that called it in Android Studio.
This is a part of the code of my fragment.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), HelpActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code of my activity:

```
public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
       
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for is communication from Activity to a fragment or vice versa so there are many ways like you can implement interface or you can use concept of shared view model.

Please check this answer :
[Communicating between a fragment and an activity - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247954/communicating-between-a-fragment-and-an-activity-best-practices)